# Find $a$ if $\{\sin(a), \sin(2a), \sin(3a)\} = \{\cos(a), \cos(2a), \cos(3a)\}$

Tags: trigonometry

Find all values of $a$ such that the sets $\{\sin(a), \sin(2a), \sin(3a)\}$ and $\{\cos(a), \cos(2a), \cos(3a)\}$ are congruent.

---

I've expanded out the terms in both sets, which become $$\{\sin(a), 2\sin(a)\cos(a), 3\sin(a)\cos^2(a) - \sin^3(a)\}$$ and $$\{\cos(a), (\cos(a) - \sin(a))(\cos(a) + \sin(a)), \cos^3(a) - 3 \sin^2(a)\cos(a)\}.$$ However, I am unsure as to how to proceed from here. Can someone give me a hint please?

Comment: There aren't that many solutions to $\sin a = \cos a$.  I'd just check which of them also give you equality at the other two coordinates.

Comment: But when talking about sets, all we need is that we have the same elements each time. We don't necessarily have to have $\sin(a) = \cos(a),$ we could have $\sin(a) = \cos(3a).$

Comment: Ah.  You're correct.  I hadn't realized they were sets and not ordered triples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the start of a solution:

In order for those sets to be equal, we need one of the following $\sin a = \cos a$, $\sin a = \cos 2a$, or $\sin a = \cos 3a$. We split our search into three cases, and make use of the identity $\sin A-\cos B = 2\sin(\tfrac{B-A}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4})\sin(\tfrac{B+A}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4})$

Case I: $\sin a = \cos a$

We must have $0 = \sin a - \cos a = 2\sin(-\tfrac{\pi}{4})\sin(a-\tfrac{\pi}{4})$, which means $\sin(a-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$.

Case II: $\sin a = \cos 2a$

We must have $0 = \sin a - \cos 2a = 2\sin(\tfrac{a}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4})\sin(\tfrac{3a}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4})$, which means $\sin(\tfrac{a}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$ or $\sin(\tfrac{3a}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$.

Case III: $\sin a = \cos 3a$

We must have $0 = \sin a - \cos 3a = 2\sin(a-\tfrac{\pi}{4})\sin(2a-\tfrac{\pi}{4})$, which means $\sin(a-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$ or $\sin(2a-\tfrac{\pi}{4})$

So $\{\sin a, \sin 2a, \sin 3a\} = \{\cos a, \cos 2a, \cos 3a\}$ can only hold if one of the following hold:

$\sin(\tfrac{a}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$, or $\sin(a-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$, or
$\sin(\tfrac{3a}{2}-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$, or $\sin(2a-\tfrac{\pi}{4}) = 0$.

So simply solve each of these equations to get a small list of possible values of $a$ (modulo $2\pi$), and then test each one of those to see which ones satisfy $\{\sin a, \sin 2a, \sin 3a\} = \{\cos a, \cos 2a, \cos 3a\}$.